# How to backup mysql database on regular basis using php code

Tags: php, mysql

I want to backup mysql database on regular basis like weekly using php script. Is this possible if yes can you tell me the site or code over here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many answers on this site and on google. Both easily found.
http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php
http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Comment: Writing custom PHP code to generate a reliable backup of your database server is of course not as straighforward as simply running `mysqldump` and other specific tools. But this question suggests that your approach is to get the code written by someone else :-?

Comment: Could you tell me the reason to Down Vote... I have tried everything on net but could not find any solution so I'm here .....????

Answer (score 0):

A simple PHP function to do this job for us and we can call that function using **Cron Job** in regular time interval.

Ref : http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/mysql-database-backup-php

Comment: By definition, I wouldn't trust any backup tool that makes use of the legacy deprecated to-be-removed mysql extension. Yours even uses `addslashes()` to escape data!

Answer (score 0):

> `

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","uname","pswrd");
$qry="show databases";
$rs=mysql_query($qry); 
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs,MYSQL_BOTH))
{
    if($row[Database]!="information_schema")
      {
        if($row[Database]!="mysql")
         {
                $fname1="/Your/Destination/Folder/".$row[Database].".sql.gz"; echo $fname1."<br>";
                    $efg   =@unlink($fname1);
                $command1 = "mysqldump --opt -uroot -proot -h localhost ".$row[Database]." | gzip>".$fname1;
            $rs_Sys1=system($command1);
            chmod($fname1,0777);

         }
     }
}


?>
```

` Run this program to get the sql backup and if you want to get the backup on a regular basis like daily/weekly, assign this program to cron (cron is a time-based job scheduler).

Comment: Could you tell me the reason to Down Vote... I have tried everything on net but could not find any solution so I'm here .....????

Comment: I didn't perform any down vote. And if anyone down voted it, that reason may be in @AlvaroG.Vicario 's comment...